# Draw "error bars" for multiple categories

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I have a data frame with (min,max) values for different categories, for example:

```
    case1     case2
 1 0.8945 0.8943867
 2 0.8950 0.8952849
```

I would like to make a plot where, for each category, only a vertical segment with short horizontal segments at the bottom and at the top is drawn: it looks like an error bar, but it doesn't have a central point. If necessary, I can live with the central point, though. Each segment must be labeled with the corresponding category name, as the boxes of a boxplot:

```
boxplot(df,cex.axis=1.5)
```

[image]

But the look of the bars must be that of functions such as `plotCI`, `segments`, etc.:

```
require(plotrix)
x=0:1
plotCI(x,apply(df,2,mean),li=df[1,],ui=df[2,],xlab="categories",ylab="values")
```

[image]

This looks fine, but the x-axis is numerical, while I need category names on the x-axis. Also, I don't like the bars to be so far away from each other, and so close to the plot margins. Is it possible to put them closer to the center, as for the boxes of a boxplot?

Comment: Try looking at the answer I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34073608/2572423). In addition, please add sample or dummy data to make your question reproducible.

Comment: `arrows(1:2, unlist(dd[1, ]), 1:2, unlist(dd[2, ]), code = 3, angle = 90)` instead of `plotCI`

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the comment. I put sample data in the first lines of the post. If you explain me what else I should add, I will do when I'm back home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two possibilities:

- Without `ggplot2`:

  ```
  require(plotrix)
  plotCI(apply(df,2,mean),li=df[1,],ui=df[2,],xlab="categories",ylab="values")
  axis(side = 1, at = c(1,2), labels = c("case1", "case2"))
  ```

[image]

- With `ggplot2`:

First redefine your `data.frame`:

```
df2 = data.frame(vmin =  c(0.8945, 0.8943867), vmax=c(0.8950, 0.8952849), case=c("case1", "case2"))
```

Then, use `geom_errorbar`

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df2, aes(ymin = vmin, ymax = vmax, x = case))
p + geom_errorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: cool, thanks! In the solution without `ggplot2`, do you know if it's possible to put the two bars closer to each other? Leaving all that white space in the middle of the plot is unsightly, so I'd like to leave more space between the bars and the plot borders (like in the `ggplot2` solution).