# Boxplot with Summarized and Grouped Data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have the following pre-summarized cost data:

| MeanCost | Std | MedianCost | LowerIQR | UpperIQR | StatusGroup | AgeGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 700 | 500 | 650 | 510 | 780 | Dead | Young |
| 800 | 600 | 810 | 666 | 1000 | Alive | Young |
| 500 | 200 | 657 | 450 | 890 | Comatose | Young |
| 300 | 400 | 560 | 467 | 670 | Dead | Old |
| 570 | 600 | 500 | 450 | 600 | Alive | Old |
| 555 | 500 | 677 | 475 | 780 | Comatose | Old |
| 333 | 455 | 300 | 200 | 400 | Dead | Middle |
| 678 | 256 | 600 | 445 | 787 | Alive | Middle |
| 1500 | 877 | 980 | 870 | 1200 | Comatose | Middle |

I wish to create a boxplot with this information - similar to the one below.
Where each Color represents Status Group (blue=dead, read=alive, green=comatose).
And each grouped cluster represents an age group (left cluster=young, middle cluster=middle, right cluster=old).

[image]

I know that I don't have min and max, so whiskers are not necessary.  
I want to code this in R, and any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
 dattest<- data.frame(
  Mean_Cost = c(700,800,500,300,570,555,333,678,1500), 
  Std = c(500,600,200,400,600,500,455,256,877), 
  Median_Cost = c(650,810,657,560,500,677,300,600,980), 
  LowerIQR = c(510,666,450,467,450,475,200,445,870), 
  UpperIQR = c(780,1000,890,670,600,780,400,787,1200), 
  StatusGroup = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  AgeGroup = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
```

where for StatusGroup 1=dead, 2=alive, 3-comatose 
and for AgeGroup 1=young, 2=old, 3=middle

```
 ggplot(dattest, aes(xmin = AgeGroup-.25, xmax=AgeGroup+.25, ymin=LowerIQR, ymax=UpperIQR)) + 
    geom_rect(fill="transparent", col = "blue") + 
    geom_segment(aes(y=Median_Cost, yend=Median_Cost, x=AgeGroup-.25, xend=AgeGroup+.25), col="blue") + 
    geom_point(mapping=aes(x = StatusGroup, y = Mean_Cost), col="red") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:3, labels=c("Young","Old","Middle")) + 
    theme_classic()
```

And this code is definitely not giving me what I want

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212885/producing-a-boxplot-in-ggplot2-using-summary-statistics. Please don't post data as an image. It's easier to help you if you include samples data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) such as `dput()` so we can copy/paste the data into R rather than retyping it to test possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you  - I edited it so that it a table that you can copy and paste into a CSV. I also do not think this is a duplicate because the previous post does not address how to plot the data with multiple groupings like this data.

Comment: The "grouping" you are looking for is just a standard `fill=` aesthetic. I think it would work if you just tried it. Add the code you tried to your question.

Comment: I am able to do it with one group - but not two, that's where I get stuck.

Comment: Then please add the code you tried for one group. It's much easier to edit and fix what you start then begin from scratch.

Comment: Yes - I have added it. Sorry - should've done that before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~MeanCost, ~Std, ~MedianCost, ~LowerIQR, ~UpperIQR, ~StatusGroup, ~AgeGroup,
       700L, 500L,        650L,      510L,      780L,       "Dead",   "Young",
       800L, 600L,        810L,      666L,     1000L,      "Alive",   "Young",
       500L, 200L,        657L,      450L,      890L,   "Comatose",   "Young",
       300L, 400L,        560L,      467L,      670L,       "Dead",     "Old",
       570L, 600L,        500L,      450L,      600L,      "Alive",     "Old",
       555L, 500L,        677L,      475L,      780L,   "Comatose",     "Old",
       333L, 455L,        300L,      200L,      400L,       "Dead",  "Middle",
       678L, 256L,        600L,      445L,      787L,      "Alive",  "Middle",
      1500L, 877L,        980L,      870L,     1200L,   "Comatose",  "Middle"
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(AgeGroup = factor(AgeGroup, levels = c("Young", "Middle", "Old"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = AgeGroup, fill = StatusGroup)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(
    lower = LowerIQR, 
    upper = UpperIQR, 
    middle = MedianCost, 
    ymin = MedianCost - Std, 
    ymax = MedianCost + Std),
    stat = "identity", width = 0.5)
```

[image: test.png]

### Edit

To add an "x" at the mean you can adjust the position:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(AgeGroup = factor(AgeGroup, levels = c("Young", "Middle", "Old"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = AgeGroup, fill = StatusGroup)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(
    lower = LowerIQR, 
    upper = UpperIQR, 
    middle = MedianCost, 
    ymin = MedianCost - Std, 
    ymax = MedianCost + Std),
    stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = MeanCost),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
             shape = 4)
```

[image: test2.png]

Comment: Yes - just about! I want to add a point for the mean, but when I add In the 'geom_point' code , it adds the mean markers next to the boxplots, and not on top of them.